# Which is correct: "of order of nanokelvins" or "of order nanokelvins"?

Tags: grammar, british-english, technical

I have the following sentence in my physics dissertation:

> The foundational component of atomtronic devices is the Bose-Einstein condensate, a state of matter of condensed bosons cooled to temperatures of order of nanokelvins.

Is it correct to say "of order of nanokelvins"? Or would one instead say "of order nanokelvins"?

I could not find any information elsewhere to answer this.

Comment: 'in the order of nanokelvins'

Comment: @KillingTime That's better! Thank you. Sadly I can't upvote yet, so here is a quasi-upvote: +1.

Comment: @Killing Time Are they one of those peculiar closed orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add an answer, because there seems to be something of a US-UK divide here.

> **in/of the order of** *idiom* [British]:
>
> around or about (a specified number) : approximately
>
> - The government has spent in the order of ten million dollars on the project.
> - He receives something of the order of 100 e-mails a day.

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%2Fof%20the%20order%20of)]

> **on the order of** *phrase* [North American]
>
> 1 approximately
>
> - It's a small fee, on the order of $10.
> - Private economists at Goldman Sachs expect the deficits will be on the order of $300 to $375 billion.
> - Even if economic output shrinks by 2 % this quarter, productivity would still grow on the order of 2 %.
> - Fahrenheit 9/11 has sold something on the order of 13 million tickets.
> - The whole operation appears to have cost on the order of $500,000.
> - Her appearance fee was on the order of 10,000 yuan or more.
> - The percentage of people who are university graduates in this country is still on the order of perhaps 25 percent of the adult
>     population.

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/on_the_order_of)]

However, the example  OP gives is not exactly the same. A unit not a measure phrase (eg 'mile/s' not '3 miles') occurs here. We would not say 'approximately dollars' or 'in the neighbourhood of metres'. Here, the meaning is 'in the range normally addressed by the nanokelvin unit'. While results hereabouts are few, there are reputable-looking internet examples of all the following:

- temperatures in the order of millikelvins
- temperatures of the order of millikelvins
- temperatures on the order of millikelvins.

(as are

- distances in the order of parsecs
- distances of the order of parsecs
- distances on the order of parsecs);

I'd say all three are acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for these additional sources and comments. I have accepted this as the answer for this question. I am going to go with "of the order of nanokelvins."

Answer (score 2):

I would coldly rephrase this *on the order of nanokelvins*.

Here is a an order-of-magnitude description of time.

> As of May 2010, the smallest time interval uncertainty in direct measurements is *on the order of* 12 attoseconds... 
>   [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time)

Comment: Thank you for this contribution. Are both "on" and "in" correct in this case?

Comment: @JackG - "In" sounds "off" to me.

Comment: "On the order of" sounds better to my AmE ears, possibly because I have seen it more in textbooks. I do not recall "In the order of." Why don't you search other journals at scholar.google.com? (I searched for seconds, but you should search for kelvins.) I could be wrong.

Comment: Not very official, but at scholar.google.com, I see <<"in the order of" kelvins Bose-Einstein>> yielding 543 results and <<"on the order of" kelvins Bose-Einstein>> at 1840 results. I suspect that the reviewers would understand either *in* or *on*, but slightly prefer *on the order of*. I did not analyze the journals for a BrE / AmE split. Please take a look at *Observation of vortex formation in an oscillating trapped Bose-Einstein condensate* (the top paper for *on*), but be warend you'll have to hunt for *on the order of* ... *unit* .